# Why does SqlAlchemy have connection pooling?

Tags: java, python, database, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

When a Python script finishes executing, it's dumped out of the memory(RAM) unlike JRE/Java(for e.g. Tomcat) where the application resides in memory all the time. So for a Java webapp I can visualize how connection pooling helps but for Python(or even PHP) how does it help?

So why does SqlAlchemy provide connection pooling?

Comment: Because python is not limited to scripts, it's an actual language that can be used to create full-blown servers…

Comment: It sounds like you have not developed a complex python application yet.

Comment: if it helps, SQLAlchemy's pool does not "pre-warm" itself.  It only makes the initial pool of connections as they are requested.  So if your script only connects once at a time, the pool will not be filled with connections, only what you used.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption simply isn't true. Yes, if you run a standalone script, it loads and runs once and is then removed from memory - and that is just as true of a standalone Java app. But no method of deploying a Python web app works like that; rather, the server spins up one or more permanent processes which handle multiple web requests. The code stays resident.

Comment: So if my webserver is Apache, the 'httpd' process is the 'permanent' one, right? And that is the process holding the connection pool?

Comment: Well, Apache is usually used with mod_wsgi, and that is the process that holds the connection pool, but yes.